# Comparação de uma imagem com outras (analisar se a imagem escolhida é igual as outras já pré-definidas ou não)

Tags: java, imagem, comparação

Estou tentando fazer um código em Java que compare uma imagem de entrada com outras n imagens já definidas no código. Desenvolvi, com ajuda (bastante), um código parecido, que comparava duas imagens apenas, o problema é ampliar isso. Pegar uma imagem só e sair comparando com várias outras, não estou sabendo fazer.

**O que tenho:**

```
public static boolean compareImage(BufferedImage image1, BufferedImage image2){
    if (image1.getWidth()!= image2.getWidth()|| image1.getHeight() != image2.getHeight()){
        return(false);
                }
    for (int x=0; x<image1.getWidth(); x++){
        for(int y=0; y<image1.getHeight(); y++){
            if(image1.getRGB(x,y)!=image2.getRGB(x,y)){
                return(false);
```

Comment: Que tal transformar as imagens a ser comparadas em uma lista e fazer um laço passando cada indice dessa lista como  um parametro, e a imagem que você quer comparar com esta lista como outro parametro?

Comment: É exatamente na parte de fazer essa lista que me perco, não sei exatamente como listar as imagens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode armazenar as imagens numa lista, e fazer um laço para comparar essa lista com a imagem que você deseja, usando o método do seu código. Dentro desse laço, você adiciona uma condição para fazer algo quando a comparação da imagem principal e alguma da lista retornar `true` ou `false`:

```
ArrayList<BufferedImage> imageList = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();


for(int i = 0; i < imageList.size(); i++) {
   if(compareImage(image1, imageList.get(i))) {
      //faz algo se retornar true
   } else {
     //faz algo se retornar false
   }
}
```